# Complex Logarithmic conversion

Tags: abstract-algebra

i have for me a very challenging function to find, in order to transform a value, defined in [dBV/dBW], into a number defined with dimension [V/W].
This is really important in order to describe the quadratic I-V response of a diode.
In order to calculate this value i make the following computation:
$\Gamma=\frac{V_1|_{dBV}-V_2|_{dBV}}{P_1|_{dBW}-P_2|_{dBW}} ~\left[\frac{dBV}{dBW}\right]$
The main issue that i see is that the dBV is calculated with a factor 20, where the dBW is with a facotr 10.
After several calculations, considering the single logarithm values (and making the "downconversion" of each) i got:
$\left(\frac{P_1|_{W}}{P_2|_{W}}\right)^{\Gamma/2}=\left(\frac{V_1|_{V}}{V_2|_{V}}\right)$
which should be correct, because as the curve is quadratic $\Gamma=2$, thus $\left(\frac{P_1|_{W}}{P_2|_{W}}\right)=\left(\frac{V_1|_{V}}{V_2|_{V}}\right)$
someone can confirm me this calculation?
Moreover I lost my wanted dimension... how can I proceed?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved on my own my question...
Having in a plot log-log the linear approximation $y=m*x+q$
the conversion into linear becomes $y=x^m\cdot 10^{q/10}$ where the factor $10^{q/10}$ is the wanted value with the correct dimension... :)